# Reasking the same question but not with the same context

Tags: discussion

I want to translate the word "boilerplate" but no as in the general meaning but in the programming context, as in "boiletplate code". There is already a question with the general way : [Comment traduire « boilerplate » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/comment-traduire-boilerplate)

As such I'm not satisfied with the answer given in that question. The only one I could think would be the word "glu" but I'd like to find a better way to express it. So can I ask the question for the same word in a different context ?

For those who wants to judge with the context of the technical definition :

A "boilerplate code" in programmation is code that only aim is to be able to use two others part of code that aren't compatible with each other by default. This is done by doing some "translations/adaptation" of what we need to use back and forth between those two components.

For instance let say I have a data representing a date in the french way, and I have a library to perform some math on dates (add/substracting) but it take only english date. This mean I will have some specific code to do the conversion each time I need it. We call this "boilerplate code".

Comment: Yeah, by my experience that's not what *boilerplate* means in software engineering context, see also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code). That said, you can certainly ask how the kind of adapter/conversion code you described would be called in French (which would indeed be *glue* imo).

Answer (score 2):

You can very well ask a question, quoting the previous one and explaining why it's different. You might have people still flagging it as duplicate, but you can fight against it and it can be answered even if it stays flagged.

It's important to quote the other question, so that people know that you haven't just missed it.